# Handling in app purchase - fetch product identifiers from my own server

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am trying to implement in app purchases to sell songs.

The song files are stored in our server.also we will add new songs via our web application.
In this implementation, I am having the below question as i am not sure how to handle.

**From the Apple document**:-
       Apple recommends you retrieve product identifiers from your server, rather than including them in a property list. This gives you the flexibility to add new products without updating your application.

**My Question** :- if i am storing and fetching all the product
 identifiers from my server,then how the itunes knows about my in app
 purchases?for example, I have 100 songs added into my web application.
 do i need to add the below  information for 100 times

> **Reference Name**: common name for the product. This name is non-editable, and it will not be displayed in the App Store.
>
> **Product ID**: unique id for your app. Typically of the form com.company.appname.product, but it can be whatever you want.
>
> **Type**: You have 3 choices:
>               Non-consumable: only pay once (use this if you want a free-to-pro-upgrade product)
>               Consumable: pay for every download
>               Subscription: recurring payment

Please shed some light on this for me

Answer (score 5):

If you would like to sell 100 products, then yes, you must create 100 In app purchases on iTunesConnect.

The information on iTunes might look like:

> **Reference**:Song 101
>
> (This should match with your server, and is
>   what your app should download from that server) 
>   **ProductID**:com.companyName.appName.song101
>
> **Type**:Non-Consumable

The piece of apple documentation you posted suggests that you don't have to submit your app again.

> This gives you the flexibility to add new products without updating your application.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. my products are not limited to 100. product will added into the web server by admin.

Comment: what is my query is , if i am adding new product means that has to available for purchase inside the app. so i need to create product identifiers in my server.this is what said by the documentation.and i would like to know what has to be done in the iTunes portal.this part is confucing me.pls help

Comment: You say you are selling songs. When you want to sell a new song, you will need to add the information to your own server AND add the information to iTunesConnect. The information on iTunes might look like: Reference:Song 101 ProductID:appName.song101 (This should match with your server, and is what your app should download from that server)  Type:Non-Consumable

Comment: You have to manually create product Identifier for each product in iTunes, which you download from your server.

Comment: @JamesWebster: When i want to sell a new song. i will do the following things. (Reference:Song 101 ProductID:appName.song101 (This should match with your server, and is what your app should download from that server)). in this case do i need to submit my application again to apple?or simply adding product identifiers inside iTunes is enough? pls let me know

Comment: The piece of apple documentation you posted suggests that you don't have to submit your app again.